# Cannot understand how to write a loop to create an array to fill a listbox that would be able to revise the original Table

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform, excel-2016

Excel VBA - Excel 2016 with no ActiveX controls.  I am a baby/newbie dealing with government firewalls, and although I have 2016 excel, it appears the permissions do not exceed 2010 vba tools.  It has been very frustrating, as I have learned what tools have been blocked from use.

I am a little advanced.  Took some courses with Leila Gharani.  And stalk YouTube like you would not believe.  I know how to create a listbox.  Right now, I am developing a VERY SIMPLE inventory management system. That must include inventory reports, pivot tables and charts, etc.

I have created a form that is a combination data entry and listbox in one.  Listbox shows all transactions to date from all locations and for all products.  I even figured out how to ensure the most recent entries show at the top of the listbox.  This form can allow the user to enter new data or edit the current data within the Master Table.  I also have a very basic form that only allows the addition of new transactions (no listbox).

My design has gone over very well.  With one catch.  The users want me to change combination entry for, such that the listbox will update when the person chooses both a location and product to enter into a transaction.  They want the listbox to provide a complete list of transactions for the product based on the location selected. They feel this will help prevent redundant entries and allow for revisions as entries are being made if necessary.

I managed to create a listbox form that met half the request (it filters the transactions to only those associated with the product and location selected). I made it using a new worksheet where I have embedded an Excel Advanced Filter with Multiple Criteria. I learned this from a VERY OLD (2015) Video tutorial that dealt with creating a multiple criteria advanced filter in one video, then in the next video they show how to run the same filters from a userform. Key details are that the listbox has to be populated from the results table created on a new worksheet.  As such, I cannot do the second part of the task which would be to allow the user to select one of the transactions (if necessary) and make any changes required to the master data before entering any new data.

So I changed tactics, I created a new column in the original Master Data, that would update when the user selects a location and product from  the comboboxes in the entry form.  It will indicate TRUE for any row that matches the requirements and FALSE for no match.

I figured then I could do an easy loop to populate the listbox with the desired columns AND the original row columns "may" be able to be retained (somehow???).  That is again where I got stuck.  I need the listbox to contain 6 columns.  And that does not include the column with the true and false.  I know I need to use loops and variables (possibly arrays).  I searched hard to see if there were similar questions, and there were some, but they don't use the same vba language I have to use, and I was getting confused about whether the code worked or not.  Whether it truly returned columns or just one line with data separated by tabs.. And whether or not it could be selected and the entry revised if necessary.

I hope this is detailed enough for you to provide some guidance or links to posts that may help me in my endeavor.  I have not shared any code because  each time I hit a wall in regards to what the next step should be.  I will not be downloading any files, and I truly want to learn how to do this myself.

Thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry if I'm mistaken to get what you want.

Anyway, maybe the code below can give you a little help to what you want.

```
Dim rw() As Variant
Dim idx As Integer

Sub PopulateListBox()
Set Rng = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

If Application.CountA(Rng) = 1 Then
Set Rng2 = Rng
Else
Set Rng2 = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End If

With ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 6
    .ColumnWidths = "20,60,40,40,40,40"
End With

For Each Cell In Rng2
    With ListBox1
        .AddItem Cell.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    End With
Next Cell
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
Else
ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter
End If

Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
End If

If TextBox2.Value <> "" Then
Rng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=TextBox2.Value, Operator:=xlAnd
End If

Call PopulateListBox

End Sub

Sub RowNum()
Set Rng = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
If Application.CountA(Rng) = 1 Then
Set Rng2 = Rng
Else
Set Rng2 = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End If

For Each Cell In Rng2
ReDim Preserve rw(p)
rw(p) = Cell.Row
p = p + 1
Next

With ListBox1
 For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
 If .Selected(i) Then
 idx = i
 Exit For
 End If
 Next i
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Call RowNum
Range(Cells(rw(idx), 1), Cells(rw(idx), 6)).Select
TextBox4.Value = Cells(rw(idx), 1).Value
TextBox5.Value = Cells(rw(idx), 2).Value
TextBox6.Value = Cells(rw(idx), 3).Value
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If (KeyCode = vbKeyReturn) Then
Call RowNum
Cells(rw(idx), 1).Value = "'" & TextBox4.Value
ListBox1.List(idx, 0) = Cells(rw(idx), 1).Value
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If (KeyCode = vbKeyReturn) Then
Call RowNum
Cells(rw(idx), 2).Value = StrConv(TextBox5.Text, vbProperCase)
ListBox1.List(idx, 1) = Cells(rw(idx), 2).Value
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If (KeyCode = vbKeyReturn) Then
Call RowNum
Cells(rw(idx), 3).Value = StrConv(TextBox6.Text, vbProperCase)
ListBox1.List(idx, 2) = Cells(rw(idx), 3).Value
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
Else
ActiveSheet.Cells.AutoFilter
End If
Call PopulateListBox
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Yes.  I got as far as you did.  But couldn't figure out how to update the selected line.  Like you did, I had to do the filter on the worksheet.

Comment: Also how do you remove the filters when the form is unloaded?  Access to the master data must be 100% at that time to ensure the reports function properly.

Comment: Do you have to reset widths each time you fill a lost box?  Even if you define them on the prperties window?

Comment: _"how do you remove the filters when the form is unloaded?"_. You can use the If/EndIf just before the `Call PopulateListBox" in UserForm_Initialize() Sub.

_"Do you have to reset widths each time you fill a lost box? Even if you define them on the prperties window"_. As long as I know, you don't have to put the Column.Count and Column.Widths code if you already define them in the properties window.

Comment: @TammyLang, please have a look the edited code in my post. The code now select the corresponding row when one of the item in the ListBox is selected. Now you can do the update on the sheet via the Userform.

Comment: Thank you I will give this code a try within my form.  It looks like it is doing what they want it to do.  I will have edit and delete button, and the boxes only need to be filled if they select Edit, and the saved row# should be sufficient to use to delete if necessary.  Wish me luck I will be back once I do the dirty work.

Comment: Ok, tried to adapt the code and it didn't work.. :(

Comment: @TammyLang, if I may suggest, maybe try to mimic the data as seen in my image and create a test Userform where it has 5 TextBoxes with name TextBox1 to type the criteria (in my example the criteria of tb1 is column B, the Product Name), TextBox2 to type another criteria (in my example the criteria of tb2 is column C, the Region/Location), TextBox3 for editing Inv # (row number n) , TextBox4 for editing ProductName (row number n), TextBox5 for editing Region (row number n). Then add one ListBox with name ListBox1, and one CommandButton with name CommandButton1. (continue)

Comment: And finally, in the VBA editor paste the whole code in my post, then put a "stop" sign by clicking the left "bar" at `Private Sub ListBox1_Click()`. So after you run the macro and when you click one item in the ListBox, then you can F8 it to understand how the code work.

Comment: _the boxes only need to be filled if they select Edit_. Yes you can modify the code to do that, because the code in my post directly update the cell sheet and the ListBox item if in any of the "edit" tb (tb 3 to tb5)  the user type other than the original value then hit enter.

Comment: You are awesomely helpful!!  I am going to work on this until I can make it work.  So far, I have successfully caused the master data to sort based on the cells.  I am still having issues populating the listbox.  I am going to put this question as answered and keep trying.  I thank you very much!!

Comment: @TammyLang, you're welcome, glad that I can help. Just please ask if you have another question. I myself is also still learning, but I'll try my best to help. If you want to have a "delete" button, please don't forget to call again the `Sub PopulateListBox()` in that DeleteButton_Click sub, but you should be careful if the ListBox item is only one (only one row filtered data in the sheet) and it's deleted then the code will fail since there is no data to list when `Sub PopulateListBox()` is called.

Comment: @TammyLang, glad to hear that :).